# How to set order by dynamically in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, sql-order-by

I want to set order by clause dynamically. I have tried it by using `case`.

But after few cases its not working for me and I am not getting why this is happening. I have tried the following link http://www.sqlteam.com/article/dynamic-order-by this is working only for 5-6 cases after that I am getting errors of conversion.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBY = 1 THEN Pla_BattingAverage
          WHEN @OrderBY = 2 THEN Pla_HomeRuns
          WHEN @OrderBY = 3 THEN Pla_RBIs
          WHEN @OrderBY = 4 THEN Pla_StolenBases
          END DESC
```

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message and the query that gives this error?

Comment: Need the code that sets @OrderBY, i.e. the full query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't for example mix strings and integers in the results of a case expression.

You could try something like this instead:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBY = 1 THEN Pla_BattingAverage END DESC,
         CASE WHEN @OrderBY = 2 THEN Pla_HomeRuns END DESC,
         CASE WHEN @OrderBY = 3 THEN Pla_RBIs END DESC,
         CASE WHEN @OrderBY = 4 THEN Pla_StolenBases END DESC
```

Note that this will be slow as an index cannot be used. Generating the query dynamically could give better performance.

Answer (score 0):

One of [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10512081/1483) was suggested by [Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61974/mark-byers).

You can also use `ROW_NUMBER()` and sort by result of `ROW_NUMBER()` function (still one `ROW_NUMBER()` for each type of order).

The other one is to save result of first query (I assume there is no `TOP` clause) in temporary table and then use `IF` to return result.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO #results
SELECT
  a, b, c
FROM
  table
...

IF @OrderBY = 1 THEN
  SELECT * FROM #results ORDER BY Pla_BattingAverage DESC
END

IF @OrderBY = 2 THEN
  SELECT * FROM #results ORDER BY Pla_HomeRuns DESC
END

...
```

However if performance matters I would try generating query dynamically.